# what will happen if I add a file to my git repo and later add a pattern in gitignore that suggests that file is to be ignored

Tags: git, github, gitignore

Suppose I have an android project in my repo and I add the apk file. Later I add a gitignore let's say [this one](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Android.gitignore). What will happen in the future to this apk file? The file will keep on changing after each build so will it be checked by git or not? In my case, I want it to continue tracking this file.

Comment: Ignoring is about **untracked** files, i.e. ones not under version control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file will continue to be tracked. You can easily find this out just by trying:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/test
$ cd /tmp/test
$ git init
$ touch foo
$ git add foo
$ echo "foo" > .gitignore
$ git add .gitignore
$ git commit -m "initial commit"
$ echo foo > foo
```

Now, `git status` will show `modified: foo` and if you `git add foo`, it will be staged despite the `.gitignore`.